# Prestashop backend display error on Paiement and transporter page

Tags: php, if-statement, prestashop, backend

on the backend of my Prestashop Site i have an error when i try to go on the payment or transporter page.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QxAy.png)

so i'm going to the page which is said by the error and on the file i dont know how to resolve the problem because for me all is good

```
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
exit;
} class Wic_EanUpcGenerator extends Module
{   private $html = '';    
private $postErrors = array();    
private $valid_types = array('ean13', 'upc');
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is the main class file of a module, it cannot start with an "if".

Try removing

```
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}
```

(you can put it into the **construct()** just in case)